# Retain original array structure in np.where

Tags: python, numpy, numpy-slicing

Take the following example:

```py
x = np.transpose(np.array([np.arange(10), np.zeros(10, dtype=int)]))
x = np.array([x, x, x])
print("orig: \n", x)
print("")
print("indexed: \n", x[np.where(np.logical_and(x[..., 0] > 3, x[..., 0] < 7))])
```

This yields:

```
orig: 
 [[[0 0]
  [1 0]
  [2 0]
  [3 0]
  [4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]
  [7 0]
  [8 0]
  [9 0]]

 [[0 0]
  [1 0]
  [2 0]
  [3 0]
  [4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]
  [7 0]
  [8 0]
  [9 0]]

 [[0 0]
  [1 0]
  [2 0]
  [3 0]
  [4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]
  [7 0]
  [8 0]
  [9 0]]]

indexed: 
 [[4 0]
 [5 0]
 [6 0]
 [4 0]
 [5 0]
 [6 0]
 [4 0]
 [5 0]
 [6 0]]
```

But what I really want is:

```
 [[[4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]]

 [[4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]]

 [[4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]]]
```

I suppose this is happening because it's populating a new array with the matching last-dimension arrays. Is that right?

Is there a way to achieve what I want with `np.where`? If so, how? If not, is there another method that's better suited? I could use loops, but I'd prefer to use a numpy vectorized function if possible.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure of performing this with `np.where`, but potentially you could call `.reshape` on your array. Depending on how robust you need this to be (i.e. if you're going to run this on lots of different sizes/shapes of data) you'd need to come up with an elegant way of determining the reshape dimensions. Here is an example:

```
x = np.transpose(np.array([np.arange(10), np.zeros(10, dtype=int)]))
x = np.array([x, x, x])

indexed = x[np.where(np.logical_and(x[..., 0] > 3, x[..., 0] < 7))].reshape(3,3,2)
print("indexed: \n", indexed)

indexed: 
 [[[4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]]

 [[4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]]

 [[4 0]
  [5 0]
  [6 0]]]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your boolean mask:

```
In [187]: mask = np.logical_and(x[...,0]>3, x[...,0]<7    
In [188]: mask
Out[188]: 
array([[False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        False],
       [False, False, False, False,  True,  True,  True, False, False,
        False]])
```

That's (3,10) shaped; but when using in indexing the result flattens:

```
In [189]: x[mask]
Out[189]: 
array([[4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0]])
```

`np.where/nonzero` gets these indices:

```
In [190]: np.nonzero(mask)
Out[190]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6, 4, 5, 6], dtype=int64))
```

But the result is the same:

```
In [191]: x[_]
Out[191]: 
array([[4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0],
       [4, 0],
       [5, 0],
       [6, 0]])
```

Since the number of 'True' are the same for each block we can reshape:

```
In [192]: _.reshape(3,-1,2)
Out[192]: 
array([[[4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0]],

       [[4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0]],

       [[4, 0],
        [5, 0],
        [6, 0]]])
```

This kind of reshape isn't, in general possible for all boolean masks.

Let's make a different array with different values in each block:

```
In [197]: x = np.transpose(np.array([np.arange(10), np.zeros(10, dtype=int)]))
     ...: z = np.array([x, x-5, x+5])

In [198]: np.nonzero(np.logical_and(z[...,0]>3, z[...,0]<7))
Out[198]: 
(array([0, 0, 0, 1, 2, 2], dtype=int64),
 array([4, 5, 6, 9, 0, 1], dtype=int64))

In [199]: z[_]
Out[199]: 
array([[ 4,  0],
       [ 5,  0],
       [ 6,  0],
       [ 4, -5],
       [ 5,  5],
       [ 6,  5]])
```

That pulls 3 from one block, 1 from the next, and 2 from the 3rd.  We can't make one n-d array from those 3 subblocks.

Comment: Ah, yeah that's taking advantage of a special case of these arrays, whereas I was really interested in the general case. I suppose I should have chosen a better example.

Comment: Right, I added an example with a different number of selections from each block.